# How to correctly pass "this" into function?

Tags: javascript

I struggle passing `this` into my function as demonstrated below:

```
console.log('geolocation is ' + this.isGeolocating);

let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
geocoder.geocode({'location': geolocation}, function(results, status, self = this) {
    console.log('geolocation is ' + self.isGeolocating);
    if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
            console.log(results[0]);
            self.geolocated = 'success';
        } else {
            // No results found
            self.geolocated = 'error';
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        self.geolocated = 'error';
    }
});

this.isGeolocating = false;
```

`this` is properly accessible before and after the function, but how can I pass it through? `self` in my case is undefined as well.

Comment: what is `this`? I'm not seeing where you are passing the `this` value. you could also use `Function.prototype.bind` on the `function(results...)` function.

Comment: i suggest you put "this" within quotes in your title so your question doesn't look generic

Comment: Instead of passing an anonymous function, create a new fungus it .bind() and pass that.

Comment: you could use arrow notation, then `this` is `this` of the containing context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's typically three approaches. One is to assign `this` to another variable, conventionally named `self` or `that`, before the function; the variable will be captured into the function's [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
let that = this;
geocoder.geocode(..., function(...) {
    that.isGeolocating
});
```

Another is to explicitly tell the function what `this` should be, using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
geocoder.geocode(..., function(...) {
    this.isGeolocating
}.bind(this));
```

The third one is to use a [rocket function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not reassign `this`:

```
geocoder.geocode(..., (...) => {
    this.isGeolocating
});
```

Comment: rocket function? :D aka `arrow`

Comment: @JaromandaX: :D Yeah, sure, the official name is "arrow function". But when I hear "arrow" I typically think of `->`; `=>` looks more like a rocket. Doesn't it? (Also, there's Ruby.)

Comment: I did have a smile `:D`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
let myBeautifulThis = this;
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
geocoder.geocode({'location': geolocation}, function(results, status) {
  console.log('geolocation is ' + myBeautifulThis.isGeolocating);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either store a reference to `this` in a variable outside of your function, or use arrow functions.

So either

```
let self = this;
geocoder.geocode({'location': geolocation}, function(results, status) {
    // you existing code here
    // use self.isGeolocating
});
```

of just

```
geocoder.geocode({'location': geolocation}, (results, status) => {
    // using this in here will use the this of the outer scope.
    // use this.isGeolocating
});
```